# How to Resolve an Image Attachment's URL on Term_Meta?

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, graphql

I'm extending the WordPress GraphQL plugin and am trying to resolve a custom field (a featured image URL) on a custom taxonomy type.

In my wp_term_meta table, I have the custom meta_key '_topic_image'. My custom taxonomy type is called 'hashtag'. So for any given hashtag which has a featured image, '_topic_image' stores the post_id of the featured image.

I think I'm very close to resolving the data as everything displays correctly in GraphiQL, but the issue is that for every hashtag, 'null' is returned as the result, even after I add a featured image for a hashtag.

Here is the code I am using: https://gist.github.com/jkhaui/b91517dda66dc84ec3deaaa4edd9a63f

Thanks so much for any help

Answer (score 0):

Ah, stupid me. If anyone's stuck in a similar situation, the following line:

```
$topic_meta = get_term_meta( $term->id, '_topic_image', true );
```

should instead be:

```
$topic_meta = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, '_topic_image', true );
```

Now it all works fine. This has happened to me before when working with custom fields in `comment_meta`, `user_meta`, etc. Not sure why only `$post->id` seems to resolve properly? Whereas to select the id for any other object, *objectname*_id is required.

Comment: Perhaps because there is also a `term_taxonomy_id`